# Issues with displaying a map in p5.js

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, processing, p5.js

I am currently attempting to display a map in processing using a 2d array.
Currently I have this down:

```
var start_map = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
];

function drawMap(map) {
  for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
      if (map[x][y] == 0) {
        fill(51, 153, 51);
        rect((10 + 50*x), (10 + 50*y), 50, 50);
      }
      else if (map[x][y] == 1) {
        fill(0, 102, 0);
        rect((10 + 50*x), (10 + 50*y), 50, 50);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But, while I do get a map displayed, it appears to be rotated 90 degrees clockwise. What is causing this and how can I fix this?

Comment: In the future please post a [mcve]. We can't run this code because we can't see what calls the `drawMap()` function.

Comment: Because in second loop each element is one cell or `y` is x position of rect and x of first loop is y position of rect, https://jsfiddle.net/2vj6s3gz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about how the indexes of a 2D array work. Let's look at a simpler example:

```
var map = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
];
```

Where is `map[0][1]`? Where is `map[1][0]`?

A 2D array is an array of arrays. The first index selects the subarray at that index, and the second index selects the element in that subarray.

So in the simple example above, `map[0]` selects the subarray at index `0`, which is `[1, 2]`. Then `map[0][1]` selects the element in that subarray at index `1`, which is `2`.

This might seem a bit surprising if you were treating the indexes as an `x, y` pair. In that case, you'd expect `0, 1` to give you `3`, right? But it's not an `x, y` pair. It's an index into the outer array, then an index into the subarray.

In other words, it's actually a `y, x` pair. So to fix your problem, you can actually just swap the order of your indexes:

```
`map[y][x]`
```

Now you use the `y` value to select which subarray you want (which row you want), and the `x` value to select which element in that subarray you want (which column you want).